# How to define functions for any column (scalar UDF) on Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

Let's say I need to define a function with a behavior like `UPPER(string)`, we can call it `FIRSTCHAR(string)` that gets the first character of a string.
So I would like to make SQL like:

```
SELECT FIRSTCHAR(middle_name) AS middle_name_first_char, 
FIRSTCHAR(last_name) AS last_name_first_char FROM clients
```

Reading BigQuery UDF documentation is not clear how to make such functions that works over string, across any table or column. It looks like to define a function with `bigquery.defineFunction()` it needs an Input column names argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per what I know, scalar type UDF are not available yet in BigQuery. Current UDF are only table wise. So you supply table to UDF and UDF is processing it row-by-row outputting 0, 1 or many rows (depends on your implemented function) for each input row.
I remember one of Google Team member mentioned - they work on making scalar UDF available at some point

I assume your simplified example in question is just example to demonstrate point of your question, so I am not providing actual solution for this example (which is super simple use of string function(s))

> 2016-08-11 UPDATE

Scalar UDF are supported now for BigQuery Standard SQL
See examples below

**JS UDF**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION FIRSTCHAR(word STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js
  AS "return word.substring(0, 1);";
SELECT 
  FIRSTCHAR(middle_name) AS middle_name_first_char, 
  FIRSTCHAR(last_name) AS last_name_first_char 
FROM clients
```

**SQL UDF**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION FIRSTCHAR(word STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  AS (SUBSTR(word, 0, 1));

SELECT 
  FIRSTCHAR(middle_name) AS middle_name_first_char, 
  FIRSTCHAR(last_name) AS last_name_first_char 
FROM clients
```

Comment: Thanks for giving some feedback! yes, this is a simplified example, what I need includes several regex that I need to apply over different datasets.

Comment: Sure, I'll do, just waiting a little if other option appears. Thanks Mikhail!